# how to sort multiple arguments without using the sort function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

my goal is to sort three numbers into a, b, and c, with a being the largest, b being the middle, and c being the smallest. To do this, I'm required to write a function. However, I've tried multiple ways and haven't found a way to allow it to work.

```
num1 = int(input("input an integer: "))
num2 = int(input("input another integer: "))
num3 = int(input("input another integer: "))

def simple_sort(a,b,c):
    if a > b and a > c:
        return a
    if b < a and b > c:
        return b
    if c < a and c < b:
        return c

a,b,c=simple_sort(num1,num2,num3)
print(a,b,c)

#for it to be correct, when i do print(a,b,c), it should print num1, num2 and num3
#in ascending order
```

Comment: As soon as one condition is met, you are going to return that value. Also, you do not have all the possible outcome . . . what if I enter `1,2,3`? Nothing will be returned because no condition is satisfied.

Comment: `return sorted([a,b,c], reverse=True)`

Comment: @sahasrara62 OP stated in title "without using sort function" -- presumably this includes both `.sort` and `sorted`

Comment: maybe write a sort algo then

Comment: Google sorting algorithms

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp actually turns out that I can, but, the main requirement is to create my own simple_sort() function, but I'm not sure how to incorporate sort(), .sort, or sorted in this

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/ a simple insertion sort which you can implement

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning one value (`a`, `b`, or `c`) where you need to return a `tuple` or `list`.

```py
def simple_sort(a,b,c):
    if a < b:
        a,b = b,a
    # above guarantees that a > b

    if c > a:
        return (c,a,b)
    elif c > b:
        return (a,c,b)
    else:
        return (a,b,c)

values = list(map(int,input("Input three integers separated by spaces: ").split()))
print(simple_sort(*values))
```

Comment: You can simplify this by just ensuring that `a > b`, swapping if necessary. Then you only have three cases to check, depending on whether `c` is the largest, middle, or smallest value.

Comment: it's better to write a sorting algorithm

Comment: @chepner thank you so much, the first one worked for me, although I had to flip the < and > because it's supposed to be in ascending order.

Comment: @sahasrara62 This *is* a sorting algorithm, if you know in advance there are only three numbers to sort.

Comment: @chepner works only for that case

Comment: @sahasrara62 It's *literally* the only case being asked about.

Comment: No need to convert the instance of `map` to a list first; iterators can be unpacked directly: `simple_sort(*map(...))`.